# Iterating through checkboxes in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

i thought about making an Url shortener app. That's how the GUI looks like:
[image]

Now i have 2 "big" problems because i've never done such things so far.
The first one:
In order to see which checkbox(es) has(have) been checked i need to iterate through them all. How do i do that? because i just dragged&dropped them into my app. I know i should put them into a QListWidget or something like that but i don't know which one.

The second:
How do i submit the link from my app to these url shortener sites and get them back? I'm fairly new to such things. Could you point me to some good tutorials on how to do that? is there an app written in qt so i could look into it's code?

Comment: See [QObject::findChildren()](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/qobject.html#findChildren-2).

Comment: Have a look at http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qbuttongroup.html, and http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qgroupbox.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [QObject::findChildren()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#findChildren)

```
QList<QCheckBox *> l_checkboxes = parentWidget.findChildren<QCheckBox *>();
```

where parentWidget is your dialog.

Also, as it performs the search recursively, i would put all checkboxes into a QFrame, QGroupBox, or similar, to reduce the search to such parent widget.

For the second part. It varies for each url shortener. I never worked with em, but, you prolly will have to either:

1. use the api
2. Make http post requests as if you were sending
   the form from their respective pages.

You can start looking [Qt HTTP requests on Google](https://www.google.es/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Qt+http+requests&oq=Qt+http+requests&gs_l=hp.3..0i19j0i8i30i19.1717.4942.1.5102.16.10.0.6.6.0.111.759.9j1.10.0....0.0..1c.1.20.hp.0WFWMmEGuyA&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49478099,d.d2k,pv.xjs.s.en_US.MzTIAy2H0K0.O&fp=fbb943839553ca9f&biw=1280&bih=899)

Comment: I wrote something about second question. Not much, tho. You should make a post for each question in the future.

Comment: Probably easiest would be to ask the provider for the API. But i highly doubt you will get an API access for all sites. Still leaves the possibility to bot a real conversation with te server.

Comment: Yup, the api is the best option, but never worked with url shorteners, dunno which of them offers one. thats why i put that second option

Comment: @trompa "parentWidget is your dialog", what's that?

Comment: Your main window or dialog... But, as i said, you should group the checkboxes inside a QFrame or QGroupbox

Comment: @trompa i've grouped them already intro a QGroupBox see screenshot (http://s1.directupload.net/images/130723/gubfeia4.png) the in my mainwindow.cpp file under ui->setupUi(this); i've added QList<QCheckBox *> l_checkboxes = QMainWindow.findChildren<QCheckBox *>();

Comment: No, instead QMainWindow. use the groupbox  QList<QCheckBox *> l_checkboxes = your_group_box.findChildren<QCheckBox *>()

Comment: ok the name of my Qgroupbox is groupBox (http://s7.directupload.net/images/130723/xl62drv9.png), replaced QMainWindow with groupBox, gives error: 'groupBox' was not declard in this scope.

Comment: ui.groupbox? How are you accessing to other widgets of your form?

Comment: ui->widgetname , that's how i access other widgets, but in this case it doesn't work, i get error.
http://s7.directupload.net/images/130723/mjkp9lkf.png

Comment: Ui->groupbox->findchildren its a pointer to object. The error says it already

Comment: QList<QCheckBox *> l_checkboxes = ui->groupBox->findChildren<QCheckBox *>()

Comment: wow man thanks, that worked. So that line of code populates a Qlist with checkboxes from the groupBox, yes? now i can iterate the list to check which one is checked etc. ?